# The C compiler "/usr/bin/cc" is not able to compile a simple test program. flutter

Tags: compiling, cmake, flutter

```
####@flash:~/Documents/app_dev/test_one$ dart run jni:setup -p jni -s src/calculation
selecting source directories: [src/calculation, /home/####/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/jni-0.7.2/src]
Target newer than source, skipping build.
+ [.dart_tool/jni/jni_native_build_JKXCIO] cmake /home/####/Documents/app_dev/test_one/src/calculation
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 11.4.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- broken
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/####/Documents/app_dev/test_one/.dart_tool/jni/jni_native_build_JKXCIO/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/####/Documents/app_dev/test_one/.dart_tool/jni/jni_native_build_JKXCIO/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".

CMake Error at /snap/flutter/141/usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:60 (message):
  The C compiler

    "/usr/bin/cc"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.
```

It fails with the following output:

```
Change Dir: /home/#####/Documents/app_dev/test_one/.dart_tool/jni/jni_native_build_JKXCIO/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/gmake cmTC_fcc09/fast && /usr/bin/gmake -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_fcc09.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_fcc09.dir/build
gmake[1]: Entering directory '/home/#####/Documents/app_dev/test_one/.dart_tool/jni/jni_native_build_JKXCIO/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_fcc09.dir/testCCompiler.c.o
/usr/bin/cc    -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_fcc09.dir/testCCompiler.c.o   -c /home/####/Documents/app_dev/test_one/.dart_tool/jni/jni_native_build_JKXCIO/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCCompiler.c
Linking C executable cmTC_fcc09
/snap/flutter/141/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_fcc09.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/cc    -B/snap/flutter/current/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9 -B/snap/flutter/current/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -B/snap/flutter/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -B/snap/flutter/current/usr/lib/ -L/snap/flutter/current/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9 -L/snap/flutter/current/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/snap/flutter/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/snap/flutter/current/usr/lib/ -lblkid -lgcrypt -llzma -llz4 -lgpg-error -luuid -lpthread -ldl -lepoxy -lfontconfig -B/snap/flutter/current/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9 -B/snap/flutter/current/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -B/snap/flutter/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -B/snap/flutter/current/usr/lib/ -L/snap/flutter/current/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9 -L/snap/flutter/current/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/snap/flutter/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/snap/flutter/current/usr/lib/ -lblkid -lgcrypt -llzma -llz4 -lgpg-error -luuid -lpthread -ldl -lepoxy -lfontconfig  CMakeFiles/cmTC_fcc09.dir/testCCompiler.c.o  -o cmTC_fcc09 
/snap/flutter/current/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/liblto_plugin.so: error loading plugin: /snap/flutter/141/usr/bin/../../lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.33' not found (required by /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/liblto_plugin.so)
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_fcc09.dir/build.make:87: cmTC_fcc09] Error 1
gmake[1]: Leaving directory '/home/####/Documents/app_dev/test_one/.dart_tool/jni/jni_native_build_JKXCIO/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
gmake: *** [Makefile:121: cmTC_fcc09/fast] Error 2




CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:8 (project)



Command exited with status code 1
+ [.dart_tool/jni/jni_native_build_JKXCIO] cmake --build .

gmake: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.

Command exited with status code 2
+ [.dart_tool/jni/jni_native_build_KGJRRZ] cmake /home/#####/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/jni-0.7.2/src
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 11.4.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- broken
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/####/Documents/app_dev/test_one/.dart_tool/jni/jni_native_build_KGJRRZ/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/#####/Documents/app_dev/test_one/.dart_tool/jni/jni_native_build_KGJRRZ/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".

CMake Error at /snap/flutter/141/usr/share/cmake-3.16/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:60 (message):
  The C compiler

    "/usr/bin/cc"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: /home/####/Documents/app_dev/test_one/.dart_tool/jni/jni_native_build_KGJRRZ/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
    
    Run Build Command(s):/usr/bin/gmake cmTC_c70af/fast && /usr/bin/gmake -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_c70af.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_c70af.dir/build
    gmake[1]: Entering directory '/home/#####/Documents/app_dev/test_one/.dart_tool/jni/jni_native_build_KGJRRZ/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
    Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_c70af.dir/testCCompiler.c.o
    /usr/bin/cc    -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_c70af.dir/testCCompiler.c.o   -c /home/#####/Documents/app_dev/test_one/.dart_tool/jni/jni_native_build_KGJRRZ/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCCompiler.c
    Linking C executable cmTC_c70af
    /snap/flutter/141/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_c70af.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
    /usr/bin/cc    -B/snap/flutter/current/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9 -B/snap/flutter/current/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -B/snap/flutter/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -B/snap/flutter/current/usr/lib/ -L/snap/flutter/current/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9 -L/snap/flutter/current/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/snap/flutter/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/snap/flutter/current/usr/lib/ -lblkid -lgcrypt -llzma -llz4 -lgpg-error -luuid -lpthread -ldl -lepoxy -lfontconfig -B/snap/flutter/current/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9 -B/snap/flutter/current/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -B/snap/flutter/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -B/snap/flutter/current/usr/lib/ -L/snap/flutter/current/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9 -L/snap/flutter/current/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/snap/flutter/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/snap/flutter/current/usr/lib/ -lblkid -lgcrypt -llzma -llz4 -lgpg-error -luuid -lpthread -ldl -lepoxy -lfontconfig  CMakeFiles/cmTC_c70af.dir/testCCompiler.c.o  -o cmTC_c70af 
    /snap/flutter/current/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/liblto_plugin.so: error loading plugin: /snap/flutter/141/usr/bin/../../lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.33' not found (required by /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/liblto_plugin.so)
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_c70af.dir/build.make:87: cmTC_c70af] Error 1
    gmake[1]: Leaving directory '/home/####/Documents/app_dev/test_one/.dart_tool/jni/jni_native_build_KGJRRZ/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
    gmake: *** [Makefile:121: cmTC_c70af/fast] Error 2
    
    

  

  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:8 (project)



Command exited with status code 1
+ [.dart_tool/jni/jni_native_build_KGJRRZ] cmake --build .

gmake: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

Comment: How did you install the C compiler? Are you using snap or APT for it?

Comment: Do: `sudo apt install build-essential`.That meta-package includes what you need.

Comment: So your system /usr/bin/gcc needs libc6 of version 2.35, and is picking up an older version, 2.33, from some flutter library.  Maybe you should be running the equivalent gcc from flutter instead of the system version. Check the CC definition in the makefile.